# MitmProxy cannot start in Ubuntu: Error starting proxy server: error(98, 'Address already in use')

Tags: https, port, mitmproxy

I am willing to use MitmProxy to intercept https traffic in my computer. I followed the [installation document here](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/stable/install.html) in Ubuntu. After complete, I try to run "mitmproxy" in Terminal and got this error.

```
Error starting proxy server: error(98, 'Address already in use')
```

I tried to check if some process is using port 80 but not found.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

mitmproxy defaults to port 8080, so this looks like you already have an application running on port 8080.

Comment: Thankyou. I check the process using 8080 and find out Tomcat is running.